# How do you turn on the cache in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using CakePHP. I have an action in a controller that produces the static content pages of an app. I want to cache this entire action/view. The controller is Pages and the action is Main. I am not seeing the cached files for the view appear in the tmp/cache folder.

- I have uncommented the Cache.check setting in core.php, so it reads:

  Configure::write('Cache.check', true);
- I have added the cache helper to the pages controller:

  var $helpers = array('javascript','cache');
- I have told the controller to cache the action called "main":

  var $cacheAction = array('main/'=>86400);
- I have confirmed there are *other* cache files (the model cache) in the app/tmp/cache folder from today, so I know this isn't a permissions issue.

Here is the top of my pages controller:

```
var $name = 'Pages';
var $helpers = array('Javascript','Cache');
var $uses = array();
var $components = array('Authentication','Security');
var $cacheAction = array('main/'=>86400);
```

I am not sure what I am missing to enable the cache of a view in CachePHP. Am I missing something? Any ideas?

Comment: have you got any solution for this? m trying for the same

Answer (score 0):

Dumb checks, sorry, but just to make sure:

**Capitalise the words 'javascript' and 'cache'**

i.e. `var $helpers = array('Javascript','Cache');`  not as you have pasted.

Ensure you've added

`var $cacheAction = array('main/'=>86400);` and

`var $helpers = array('Javascript','Cache');`

at *Class* level in the appropriate controller.

It might be worth trying the helper declaration in the app_controller.

I don't know if you're on Windows or something more sensible. If you're on Linux or OSX or whatever, in a console window, change directory to `app/tmp` and `chmod -R 777 .` It's probably worthwhile recursively `chown` & `chgrp` to whatever the web user is, too.

Delete all the cache files - leave the directories there.

Try again.

Comment: Thanks. Not dumb checks. I made them capital, but I have never seen CakePHP be case sensitive with these. Deleted cache and confirmed CakePHP recreated model cache files in tmp, etc.

Comment: Can you explain "It might be worth trying the helper declaration in the app_controller". I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

here is a brand new post on view caching for cakephp, you might want to check it out http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2011/02/05/make-your-cakephp-app-ridiculously-faster-with-view-caching/